# Killing all Instances of running Excel process

Tags: excel-2007

I have an application where I have used a Webbrowser component in a wrapper to open an Excel worksheet.  Now, when I press the exit key of the form containing the Webbrowser component, I would like it to find that particular Excel instance (leaving others) and kill it.

How can I do that?